# gcc optimisation effect on loops with apparently constant variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, optimization

I was optimizing a c++ code in which I encountered a situation that can be simplified as follows.

Consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

bool hit = false;

void F()
{
   this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
   hit = true;
}

int main()
{
   thread t(F);

   while (!hit)
      ;

   cout << "finished" << endl;
   t.join();
   return 0;
}
```

This basically starts a thread which after a second will change the value of `hit` to `true`. At the same time the code enters an empty loop which will continue until the `hit`'s value will become `true`. I compiled this with `gcc-5.4` using `-g` flag and everything was fine. The code will output `finished` and ends. But then I compiled it with `-O2` flag and this time the code got stuck in the loop infinitely.

Looking at the disassembly, the compiler had generated the following, which is the root cause of the infinite loop:

> jmp    0x6ba6f3           ! 0x00000000006ba6f3

OK, so clearly, the compiler has deduced that `hit`'s value is `false` and it will not change in the loop so why not assume that it is an infinite loop without considering that another thread may change its value! And this optimization mode is added in the higher level (`-O2`). Since I'm not exactly an optimization flag expert, can anyone tell me which of them is responsible for this result so I can turn it off? And would turning it off have any major performance cost for other pieces of code? I mean, how much this pattern of code is rare?

Comment: use `std::atomic<bool>`.

Comment: What happens if you declare `hit` as volatile?

Comment: @Milack27 yes it solves the problem! Man, there is many things in c++ that I still don't know about!

Comment: @Sinapse: No, actually, it doesn't. It only made the symptoms go away - _for now_. Trouble is, it's still Undefined Behavior, and if you change one line of code the optimizer may make some new decisions.

Comment: @MSalters I understand the problem generally, what volatile solves is the compiler's optimization alone! But since bool (1 byte) would not face tearing in read/write and `cache coherence` does not matter in the example above (it will only cause to loop some more than it actually needs), we are good to go JUST IN THIS case of course

Comment: @Sinapse: The Standard is very clear on this point. It's not "tearing" or "cache coherence", the Standard doesn't talk about that. Two accesses to a single variable like this **must** be ordered, on penalty of Undefined Behavior. `volatile` does not affect ordering and does not cure the Undefined Behavior. As far as the Standard is concerned, each thread can get _its own `volatile bool hit`_ !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code has Undefined Behavior. You're modifying `hit` from one thread and reading it form another, without synchronization.

Optimizing `hit` to `false` is a valid outcome of Undefined Behavior. You can solve this by making `hit` a `std::atomic<bool>`. This makes if well-defined, and blocks the optimization.

Comment: Yes this too will solve the problem (I think volatile will do it more efficiently for my case)   but OMG!! Just how the compiler knows it when you define the variable as atomic?! I mean volatile make sense since you are adding a qualifier but in case of std::atomic, how compiler will deduce that it may change in another thread??

Comment: Guess what! There are volatile members inside the `std::atomic<bool>` class. :)
Try opening the "atomic" file from g++ include folder, you can see them there.

Comment: Nice, that was worthy!

Comment: @Milack27: Implementation detail.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read/write `hit` from several threads at the same time then you need some kind of synchronization otherwise you'll introduce a race condition. You can either make `hit` an `std::atomic<bool>` or add a `mutex` that needs to be locked when accessing `hit` value. If you just want to wait for thread to finish its job than you can leave just `thread.join()` (and print "finished" after it) without introducing any additional flags.

Answer (score 1):

By declaring `hit` as volatile, you're telling the compiler that this variable can be modified by external factors at any time, so the compiler won't assume that its value won't change along your `main` function.

As long as there is only one thread writing to the `hit` variable, your code should work properly, with no race conditions involved. However, when you're dealing with multiple threads, it's always safer to use synchronization tools, like atomic objects, mutexes and semaphores, as already mentioned in the other answers here.

Comment: `volatile` [fails to provide the necessary ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4558031/15416).

Comment: Yes. As I said, _it's always safer to use synchronization tools_. Using `volatile` should work properly _in this case_.